# Generate Invoice Number for Multi user environment in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am generating invoice numbers using Max function and adding 1 to the last invoice number. Very straightforward. but i applied this into Multi User environment getting problem. because two users open a invoice window at a same time both could get same id, invoice number should be the first thing to appear and not the last so i cannot use identity (auto generate id) for invoice number. I want to generate invoice number for Multi User environment windows form application in C#...

The other problem is what will happen two users accessing and updating the same record same time.

I hope you will understand the problem. i read about the Optimistic vs. Pessimistic locking but i need a solution. so can anyone please reply to me

Comment: Just use an IDENTITY column and change your UI so that it only appears once a record is saved. Why would you want to display this information if a record hasn't been saved yet? A record should be saved once it is complete, so if a user cancels the invoice creation you won't be left with empty records.

Comment: Yes, use an identity column - the next review makes sure you are fired. It is an antipattern because invoice numbers have legal requirements that identity columns can not fulfill. Too many reasons things may go wrong here, including gaps due to sql server restart behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Have a **different database table** that will store the max invoice number.
When a user opens the invoice window, run a **stored procedure** to:

- Lock the table
- Get the current number
- Store the current+1 number
- Unlock the table
- Return the current+1 number

This will ensure that even though there are simultaneous requests you will always get a unique invoice number.

The flip side:
1. This stored procedure cannot run simultaneously for multiple users so it would be a bottleneck in case of high traffic.
2. There will be holes in the invoice numbers - holes where the invoices are cancelled.

If you are not positive with this approach then the invoice number must be generated at the time of saving and it would be an `IDENTITY` column but you have mentioned that users would like to see the invoice number when they start working on the invoice.

*Update:*

I found an excellent article that elaborates the above approach using `sp_getapplock`. The article link is [HERE](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3202/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-the-same-sql-server-stored-procedure-at-the-same-time/). I would recommend to use this approach.

Comment: Flip Side 1 is a minor issue - properl programmed you can handle thousands of reuqests per second. Not a real issue. 2 is an architectuer problem...

Answer (score 1):

Generally the problem is your application makes bad requirements and the approach is not suitable.

- The invoice number should not be allocated when the invoice is created for editing, but when it is put into the system for transaction. This way an abort does not leave gaps.
- Collect the invoice details, then create the insert via a stored procedure that puts the proper locks in place. This is trivial - if you know how to put either a lock on the relevant table, or use an applock for this SP.

Generally this is one of the few places a stored procedure makes sense. Generates a non-accounted for invoice with 0 line items so your application then can add the details. Voila, problems solved. If the user aborts, mark the invoice as "cancelled" and finished.

Comment: Thanks for your idea but the thing is my client wants to appear invoice number when form load so i cannot use identity and it is a mulit user environment system. pls help me....

Comment: Then your client needs a reality check. That will lead to a LOT of canceled invoices. Anyhow, the approach is the same - allocate the invoice number with a stored procedure.

Comment: Can i know generally POS systems invoice number how to generate. And i have a another problem when i use identity column for invoice number and after insert a value and retrieve last inserted value using IDENT_CURRENT but in multi user environment what will happen two user doing transaction at same time....

Comment: Any POS worth more than a cent will generate the number on save, and not on showing the form. THe rest is reckless programming - a requirement without justification and in violatin of proper accounting principles.

Comment: Thank you for the replies.. sorry asking again i couldn't understand you last comment. can u pls detail the answer.. and what shall a i do for my problem give me a good solution.... give some example code etc... thanks again @TomTom

Answer (score -1):

The auto increment column is the best solution. this is what we call Identity column in SQL Server.

If in your case you are not able to use it you could make a thread safe method in your server side code to generate the invoice id based on a static attribute.
Make sure that you are using a service in a single instance mode.

```
static long invoiceId = getMaxFunction();
...
...
public long GenerateInvoiceId()
{
    lock(this)
    {
        return invoiceId++;
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is what most people call a "you are fired" antipattern. ID are seriously problematic and only work in the most trivial case (for example in some companies we have multiple series of invocie numbers for different subgroups). You also are open to gaps in cae of a server resetart unless you set a flag and you are generally open for gaps in case of failing transactions. VERY bad - ID is good for what it is, it is not a sequence for generating business identifiers.

Comment: It is even technically wrong. Evne in a web application the lock is not guaranteed to work. Ever read the documentation? lock is PER PROCCESS.

Comment: @TomTom He want a way to generate Id for invoice before inserting in the database. I already noticed that the best way is column identity in database. For the second solution consider that I am talking about single instance service that serve all clients.

Comment: @hatem87 you are correct i want to generate id before inserting in the database but your idea is good, i can go for column identity in database but after save(inserted) valued i want to retrieve last  identity value using IDENT_CURRENT but there is a problem in a multi user environment two or more users save data at a same time what will happen.... how to print exact invoice number in the invoice.. pls help me.

Comment: If really you need to display id before inserting the invoice. So when doing the save get the id inserted and check if this is not the same that you already displayed correct that in your gui and alert the user. (I am not convinced by the fact that you display the id before saving data). Else see what @TomTom said in his solution about "cancelled" status.

Comment: Another way is to create a table that contains one column (identity column). For each request add a row to this table and get the inserted id. Use this one as the invoice id but you need to remove the fact that the id auto increment (column identity).